# Improperly configured nested resource using HyperlinkedModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nested-resources

I have chosen the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org) and [drf-nested-routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) to build an API for *Products* and *ProductReports*. Here are the relevant classes:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class ProductReport(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', default=1)
```

...

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Product, ProductReport


class ProductSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Product


class ProductReportSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ProductReport
```

...

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
from rest_framework.response import Response
from models import Product, ProductReport
from serializers import ProductSerializer, ProductReportSerializer


class ProductViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer


class ProductReportViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = ProductReport.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductReportSerializer

    def list(self, request, product_pk=None):
        queryset = self.queryset.filter(product=product_pk)
        serializer = ProductReportSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, product_pk=None):
        queryset = self.queryset.get(pk=pk, product=product_pk)
        serializer = ProductReportSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

...

```
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework_nested.routers import SimpleRouter, NestedSimpleRouter
from productreports import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet)

products_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'products', lookup='product')
products_router.register(r'productreports', views.ProductReportViewSet)


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(products_router.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
)
```

When I visit `http://localhost:8000/products/1/productreports/` the following **error** is shown:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /products/1/productreports/
>   Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "productreport-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

There are a few things I am unsure about if they are correctly set up:

- `product = models.ForeignKey('Product', default=1)`
- `many=True` in `serializer = ProductReportSerializer(queryset, many=True, context={'request': request})` ... **each** product can have **many** product reports
- The `ProductReportSerializer` in general
- `lookup='product'` in `products_router = NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'products', lookup='product')`

## Update

I noticed that the error only occurs when there is **at least one associated *productreport*** for a *product*. If the *productreports* table contains no entry for a particular *product* then the API response is fine.

When I inspect the `serializer` in `ProductReportViewSet#list` I get:

```
ProductReportSerializer([
    <ProductReport: ProductReport object>, <ProductReport: ProductReport object>, 
    <ProductReport: ProductReport object>, <ProductReport: ProductReport object>, 
    <ProductReport: ProductReport object>, <ProductReport: ProductReport object>, 

'...(remaining elements truncated)...'], context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object>}, many=True):
        url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='productreport-detail')
        product = ProductSerializer():
            url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='product-detail')
            created_at = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
        user_name = CharField(max_length=256)
        created_at = DateTimeField(read_only=True)
```

Comment: A bit irrelevant to a question...I happened not to use the solution in production. What I may recommend is to try this another project that is well documented, maintained and tesed: http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes

Comment: @Sekai Somewhat. I decided not to use *drf-nested-routers* and instead [minimize routes](https://github.com/interagent/http-api-design#minimize-path-nesting)